# RSelenium - remDr$switchToWindow() not working as expected (does not switch window)

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping

I am having a strange issue with RSelenium. Here is a reproducible example:

```
#Open session:

require(RSelenium)
driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"), chromever="76.0.3809.126", port = 1220L)
remDr <- driver$client
  remDro=i0 open()
remDr$getStatus()

#Navigate to main page:

wsurl <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._state"
remDr$navigate(wsurl)

#Open child window:

webEl <- remDr$findElement("xpath","//*[@id='mw-content-text']/div/div[5]/div/ul/li[1]/a")
remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = webEl)
win.hand.m <- remDr$getCurrentWindowHandle()
webEl$sendKeysToElement(sendKeys = list("\ue008\ue007"))

#The above works as anticipated, but then I attempt to switch to the child window:

win.hands <- remDr$getWindowHandles()
win.hand.c <- win.hands[which(win.hands != win.hand.m[[1]])]
remDr$switchToWindow(win.hand.c[[1]])

#But it does not work:

remDr$getCurrentWindowHandle()[[1]] == win.hand.c[[1]]

#returns FALSE and 

remDr$getCurrentWindowHandle()[[1]] == win.hand.m[[1]]

#returns TRUE
```

The issue appears to be that the function `remDr$switchToWindow(win.hand.c[[1]])`
does nothing. Does anyone know why, or if there is an alternative?

Comment: SOLVED (as usual I found the answer 5m after posting despite searching for an hour beforehand). Use the function ```myswitch``` defined by johndharrison on this thread: https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/143. I'll leave this up in case anyone was looking up the problem here, as I can't see another answer on stack overflow.

Comment: Thank you this is priceless. Such arcane incantations.